# Got an `ResponseError` from `window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(...)`

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In `config.js` : `config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl ='/upload.do?someparameter=v';`.

And upload is successfuly done on server and returns below script with `ResponseError`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, 'https://ANOTHERDOMAIN.COM/image.jpg', '');
</script>
```

Note that the second parameter values is another domain. I guess maybe it causes the `ResponseError`. How to fix this? It must return a url with another domain.

Comment: Hi Deckard, I need some clarification. I'm confused as to why you say it uploads correctly, but then you want to insert an image link to another domain?

Comment: It uploads to Azure Blob Storage. Azure blob domain is like `https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/container/image.jpg`. And that's what I need to pass as a parameter.